# How to Deploy a Drupal Site on a Web Farm?

Tags: deployment, drupal, drupal-6

I would like to know how I should deploy a Drupal site when I'm using three servers?

Is it possible to deploy it with a Drupal module or something? If it is, how does that work?

Thanks.

**update:** I would like to know about the deployment of files and the configuration of the servers.

Comment: Are you asking about the deployment of files or the configuration of the servers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should consider using [drush](http://drupal.org/project/drush).

among other useful things (automatic download and update of the modules) 
it has a rsync wrapper that lets you synchronize files between hosts (./drush sync)

it's also used by the project [aegir](http://groups.drupal.org/aegir-hosting-system) which is "a set of modules for Drupal that helps you maintain several Drupal sites."